# How to return the strategy pyramiding number in tradingview in pinescript so that I can use it in the code itself?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

How to return the strategy pyramiding number in tradingview in pinescript so that I can use it in the code itself?

This is the original code:

```
if strategy.opentrades == 2 or entry_long
    long_stop_level := entry_price - nLoss
```

i intend to do the following but obviously it prompt error because strategy doesnt have pyramiding itself, how to resolve this?

```
if strategy.opentrades == 2 or entry_long or strategy.pyramiding ==1
    long_stop_level := entry_price - nLoss
```

Answer (score 2):

Pyramding value is not accessible.

As a workaround, you can try setting the pyramiding to 99 (strategy properties) but have a user input for it also. Then only consider whatever number is selected via the user input and simply ignore whatever is there in the strategy properties.